# Leaflet Playback: slider changes base on marker position

Tags: javascript, leaflet, playback

I am currently playing with [Leaflet Playback](https://github.com/hallahan/LeafletPlayback)

The example has a slider that count up on milliseconds and the makers are moving based on milliseconds.

My question is, if I have a marker that only move 4 times in the whole day, how can I make the slider that only have 4 sticks of timestamp based on 4 times that my marker have changed.

Comment: what do you mean with 4 sticks ?

Comment: For example, if I have an array of 4 locations with 4 different timestamp (such as 1pm on Saturday, 10pm on Saturday, 1am on Tuesday, 2pm on Wednesday) because my marker doesnt move much. I want the slider associate to the locations instead of the timestamp. Because I dont want to slide/ wait for the slide play from Saturday to Wednesday just for 4 locations changed.

Comment: There should be 4 sticks (1pm on Saturday, 10pm on Saturdat, 1am on Tuesday, 2pm on Wednesday) on the slider instead the whole bunch of stick from 1pm on Saturday to 2pm on Wednesday. I don't know how to make the slider that slide base on the location changed not every 25ms like the example.